# Creating a set & removing an element in the same line yields different result than creating a set & removing element in different line in Python. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, set

I observed a behaviour which I find strange in Python:

**Method I**

If I do:

```
numberset=set([1,2,3])
numberset.remove(1)
```

Now `numberset` is `{2, 3}`, as expected.

**Method II**

However, if I do:

```
numberset=set([1,2,3]).remove(1)
```

`numberset` is now `NoneType`, ie not even a `set`. Isn't `numberset` just the name for `set([1,2,3])`, so why is the second method results in a different `numberset` than the first?

Comment: Because `set.remove` just returns `None`. It is an in-place method that directly changes the `set` instead of returning a new one.

Comment: Please clarify your confusion. In the second case, ``numberset`` is the name for ``set([1,2,3]).remove(1)``, not ``set([1, 2, 3])``. Also take note that there is no need to use ``set`` with a list literal - user a set literal like ``{1, 2, 3}`` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That’s because the [return type of `.remove` is `None`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/set/remove): it doesn’t return anything. It only raises a `KeyError` is the value is not in the set.

Your first code would be equal to the second if you did:

```
numberset = set([1,2,3])
numberset = numberset.remove(1)
```

Which would also result in `numberset` being `None`.

If you want to put that code in one line, you can subtract elements from a set:

```
numberset = set([1, 2, 3]) - set([1])
```

Using set subtraction, you can also handle removing items that are not in the set:

```
set([1, 2, 3]).remove(4)   # raises KeyError
set([1, 2, 3]) - set([4])  # return a set with elements: 1, 2, 3
```

As pointed out in the comments, you could / should use a set literal: `{1, 2, 3}`. This is equivalent to `set([1, 2, 3])`. In the same way, you can write:

```
numberset = {1, 2, 3} - {1}
```

Finishing off with a [PEP20 - The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) quote: *“Simple is better than complex.”*